# Installing Python Modules on Windows with Multiple Python Versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I have 2 Python `3.x` versions installed on my Windows machine.

```
Python 3.8.x
Python 3.9.2
```

I want to install modules on the python 3.9 installation.

```
pip install paramiko
```

The command returns saying Requirement already satisfied.
However, `paramiko` is installed in Python 3.8.x but not Python 3.9.2.

I tried the following command which also didn't work.

```
python3.9.2 -m pip install paramiko
```

How can I install a module under the Python 3.9.2 version?

Comment: How do you typically run code with the 3.9 installation?

Comment: You could open a command prompt in the same directory as the `3.9` installation and run `python.exe -m pip install paramiko`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with below change in command

```
python3.9 -m pip install paramiko
```